# Data save in magento 2.1 product form

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax

I have added a attribute "publishers" in product upload form. 
The publisher list is coming from ajax call from the database like auto suggestion and showing like drop-down list.

The problem is when I click on the list and set the attribute value though the actual value is showing as the input value, but not saving when I click on save button. What I type in the input field is saving.

I am not sure why this is happening. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-form-part="product_form"` in input tag, we can get the values in post.